# How to provide a nested Generic in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zustand

I'm using state library [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) with typescript. I want to store an object that has at least an id:number. Now I get an error, because the nested Generic is not defined correctly. How can I fix that?

```
Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)
```

Code

```
type HasId = { id: number }

export type Product<T extends HasId> = {
  product: T | null
  setProduct: (product: T | null) => void
}

export const useProductStore = create<Product<T>>(set => ({
  product: {id: 2, color: "red", // other unknown props},
  setProduct: product => {
    set({ product })
  },
}))
```

Comment: your T in useProductStore is completely independent of the T in your type hence why it can't find T, because it is looking for a variable named T. In your function, you would need to pass an object like `HasId` in order for the compiler stop complaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation for `Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)`**

Pretty simply the reason why the compiler is throwing that error, is because there is no variable named T within your code, at least in the snippet provided

```
export type Product<T extends HasId> = {
  product: T | null
  setProduct: (product: T | null) => void
}
```

Type `Product` takes an argument T which is basically of the same type as `HasId`

**"Translated"**

```
export type Product<T extends HasId> = {
   product: object with prop id and number value ({id:4}) | null
   setProduct: (product: object with prop id and number value ({id:4}) | null) => void
}
```

In order for the compiler to stop complaining on your scenario you would need to pass a valid argument to your type, for example:

```
export const useProductStore = create<Product<{id: 2}>>(set => ({
  product: {id: 2, color: "red", // other unknown props},
  setProduct: product => {
    set({ product })
  },
}))
```

Since `{id: 2}` conforms to your generic `T`, the compiler is now happy.

For your specific scenario I think the best approach would be to ditch the generic and have a type like so:

```
export type Product = {
    product: HasId | null
    setProduct: (product: HasId | null) => void
}
```

and your function becomes

```
export const useProductStore = create<Product>(set => ({
  product: {id: 2, color: "red", // other unknown props},
  setProduct: product => {
    set({ product })
  },
}))
```

Comment: Thank You. But I don't know the value of the id. I just know that it is a number. Is there a way to express that?

Comment: Then why you need the generic? Why not making your type comply to HasId?

Comment: How can I type a data object that at least needs to fulfill the property id ?

Comment: I have edited the answer, basically does exactly the same as having the generic